# Peterson's Algorithm with some modifications

Tags: algorithm

would [Peterson's Algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peterson's_algorithm) work after flipping the turn and flag orders;
ex:

```
P0:
  turn = 1;
  flag[0] = true;
         while (flag[1] && turn == 1)
         {
             // busy wait
         }
         // critical section
         ...
         // end of critical section
         flag[0] = false;
```

=================

```
P1:
  turn = 0;
  flag[1] = true;
         while (flag[0] && turn == 0)
         {
             // busy wait
         }
         // critical section
         ...
         // end of critical section
         flag[1] = false;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it doesn't work if you flip the orders, because it allows both processes to enter the critical section simultaneously.

For example, suppose an initial state where `flag[0] = false, flag[1] = false, turn = 0`:

Process 0 runs:

```
turn = 1;  // flag[0] = false, flag[1] = false, turn = 1
```

Then context switch to process 1:

```
turn = 0;
flag[1] = true;   // flag[0] = false, flag[1] = true, turn = 0

while (flag[0] && turn == 0) {} // this evaluates to false because
    // process 0 was interrupted before it set flag[0] to true

// Process 1 enters the critical section...
```

Then context switch back to process 0:

```
flag[0] = true;   // flag[0] = true, flag[1] = true, turn = 0
while (flag[1] && turn == 1) {} // this evaluates to false

// Process 0 enters the critical section..
```

Now both processes are inside the critical section.

Setting the flag has to come first because it's the thing that the other process can't overwrite. If a process sets `turn` then as shown above the other process can overwrite it and then enter the critical section before the first process has a chance to set the flag.